# Get stderr after redirecting output to dialog gauge

Tags: bash, dialog

I am using a python file to scrape a link, but to do that it takes some time, it prints `33`, `66` and `100` normally and print the link to stderr using `sys.write.stderr(var)`

Now, I want to run this command `python file.py | dialog --gauge "Doing stuffs" 10 35 0`

and want to pipe the stdout(33, 66, 100 for updating percentage) to gauge and get the sterr to a variable.

```
{ 
    python3 file.py 2>&3 | dialog --gauge "Doing stuffs" 10 35 0; 
} 3>&1
```

this command runs dialog correctly and then print the stderr, but I can't take its output unless It is made to run in subshell. But doing so will make the dialog disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this function definition, which writes percentages to *stdout* and commentary to *stderr*, as a stand-in replacement for your `python` program:

```
thing() { for f in {10..100..10}; do sleep 0.5; echo "$f"; echo "Got $f" >&2; done; }
```

You can capture the *stderr* output from `thing` while still presenting a gauge:

```
{ info=$( ( thing 2>&4 | dialog --gauge 'Gauge' 10 40 0 >&3 ) 4>&1 ) ; } 3>&1
printf "GOT> %s\n" "$info"
```

Here we capture `thing`'s *stderr* to *fd 4*, and send the output from `dialog --gauge` temporarily to *fd 3*. After assigning the variable `$info` from *fd 4* we redirect *fd 3* back to *stdout*. If you don't need that final reassignment you can simplify the expression by removing the outer curly braces and redirection, leaving the gauge display on *stderr*:

```
info=$( ( thing 2>&4 | dialog --gauge 'Gauge' 10 40 0 >&2 ) 4>&1 )
printf "GOT> %s\n" "$info"
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks it worked, Thankyou sir very much

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for you would be to store the standard error to a file, and then assign the content of this file to a variable after your script finishes.

```
python file.py 2> ErrorFile | dialog --gauge "Doing stuffs" 10 35 0
MY_STDERR=$(<ErrorFile)
```

If you don't want to use intermediate file, here's another way (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56577569/8529284), where you can also see the explanation):

```
{ MY_STDERR="$( { python file.py | dialog --gauge "Doing stuffs" 10 35 0; } 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- )"; } 3>&1;
```

Comment: That is how I am using it currently, just wanted to not create an file. sadly, OKAY Thanks for help

Comment: @decipher updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be something like this:

```
x=$( { dostuff | 
       dialog --gauge "Doing stuffs" 10 35 0 >/dev/tty 2>/dev/null; } 2>&1 )
```

Here,

- the stdout of `dialog` (the progress bar) is redirected directly to the terminal bypassing anything else
- the stderr of `dialog` is sent to `/dev/null` so we don't capture any garbage from there
- the stdout of `python` goes to `dialog` via the pipe as usual, and
- the stderr of `python` is redirected (outside the group) to the "stdout" provided by the command substitution, and captured by the shell

Of course the redirection to `/dev/tty` means that the progress bar will be printed even if the output of the whole thing is redirected somewhere else. That may or may not be what you want (but the mess of terminal control codes that `dialog` outputs is also probably not something that's very useful anywhere other than a terminal anyway).

That'll also hide any errors from `dialog`, but the exit status of the whole assignment is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, so you can check that. Or use `set -o pipefail` to see if either command in the pipeline fails.

Tested with a script like this as `dostuff`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in 0 1 2 3 4 5; do
    echo $((x * 20));
    sleep .5;
done
echo "this is the result" >&2
```

Comment: @terdon, no, I'm pretty sure I didn't, I wanted both outputs of `dialog` to go to `/dev/null`. That's how I read the question anyway, that they were interested in the stderr of the Python script, not any errors from `dialog`.

Comment: Yeah, but you were redirecting the stderr of the python script too so the variable was empty.

Comment: @ilkkachu due to that $( ), the dialog is not shown, also, I got nothing in that variable as well.

Comment: Try it with `x=$( {  perl -le 'print STDOUT "out"; print STDERR "err"' >/dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1 )`, the `$x` variable will be empty. But with `x=$( {  perl -le 'print STDOUT "out"; print STDERR "err"' 2>&1 >/dev/null ; } 2>&1 )`, the variable has the `err` sting from standard error as expected.

Comment: @terdon I can get the the err string but if I don't use dialog, If I use dialog, the varisble is lost, and method like yours just runs dialog in another subshell that makes it invisible. This is the biggest problem.

Tell me how to solve this with bash only

see at the end, I edited the question

Comment: There should be a way by creating a new file descriptor, redirecting stdout to it, then redirecting stderr to stdout, and then recapturing stdout from the file descripto, but I haven't managed to get it to work so far. Ilkkachu is better at this sort of thing than I am, maybe he can figure it out.

Comment: @terdon, the redirections within the group were only on the right-hand side of the pipeline, so they only affected `dialog`. And well, still do, except... The problem I _did_ have was that I sent the progress bar output to `/dev/null` too... (because for some reason I was thinking of a GUI tool displaying the progress bar, and not using the terminal for that, oops.) Anyway, the redirection to `/dev/tty` should work. And yes, just setting up another fd might be a better option, but since I'd already started...